# play file RM audio c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

How to play an RA audio file in C#

RA audio file

Make WindowsMediaPlayer support the ra file or play a single file in another
files ra not play in WindowsMediaPlayer
code c# play in WindowsMediaPlayer
How to play an RA audio file in C#?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Use [NAudio](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NAudio)  to create an audio file reader for the RA file
here is an Example :

```
using NAudio.Wave;

class Program 
{
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    // create an audio file reader for the RA file
    WaveStream pcmReader = new RawSourceWaveStream(new FileStream("audio.ra", FileMode.Open), 
       new WaveFormat(44100, 16, 2));

    // create an output device to play the audio
    WaveOutEvent outputDevice = new WaveOutEvent();

    // start playback
    outputDevice.Init(pcmReader);
    outputDevice.Play();

    // keep running until playback finishes
    while (outputDevice.PlaybackState == PlaybackState.Playing)
    {
      System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
    }
    
    outputDevice.Dispose();
    pcmReader.Dispose();
  }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the library  NAudio  does not support RM